# Get summary of fields in child object to display in parent lwc

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, soql

I have a custom object `CaseGroup__c` which has a lookup relationship to `Case` which has a master-detail relationship with `Timer__c` and I want to get the summary time of each case  associated to a group and display it as a LWC like the Case Group example below.

I was able to get the Cases associated with each Case Group, but summary time I get is for all Cases so it ends up being 11 and 24 respectively instead of for each case. and then from here what is the best way to display the information in a LWC data table

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=True)
public static Decimal getCaseGroupTimerSummary(String groupId) {
    Decimal Sentsum = 0;
    Set<Id> caseId = new Set <Id>() ;
    for(Case cs: [SELECT Id FROM case Where CaseGroup__ =: groupId]) {
        caseId.add(cs.Id);

     }

    List<Decimal> timerList = new List<Decimal>();
    for (Timer__c tl : [SELECT sent_time__c FROM Timer__C Where Case IN: caseId] {
        timerList.add(tl.sent_time__c);
        sentSum = sentSum + tl.sent_time__c;
    }
 
    return sentSum;
   
}
```

Example Cases:

```
Case 1 :
Sent Times | Received Times
----------   --------------
 1         |        4
 2         |        5
 3         |        6
   
Case 2 :
Sent Times | Received Times
----------   --------------
 1         |        2
 1         |        2
 3         |        6
```

Would like the final table to look something like this:

```
Case Group:
Case Name| Time Spent: Sent| Time Spent: Received
------------------------------------------------
Case 1   |         6       |       15
Case 2   |         5       |       9
```

Comment: Any luck with my answer?

Comment: thank you! that was helpful

Comment: From there how would you display the result in a LWC table? From some of the examples I looked at I know you use @wire the method parameters? In this case its the groupId, but I want to display the associated caseId that were queried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could use an aggregate query to do this:
(note - I don't know what your custom field case it actually looks like - below is a guess)

```
AggregateResult[] groupedResults = [
   SELECT CaseId__c, SUM(sent_time__c), SUM(recieved_time__c)
   FROM Timer__c
   WHERE CaseId__c IN: caseId
   GROUP BY CaseId__c
];
```

Then parse it like:

```
Map<Id,Result> resultMap = new Map<Id,Result>();
for (AggregateResult ar : groupedResults)  {
  Result r = new Result();
  r.sentTime = ar.get('expr0');
  r.recievedTime = ar.get('expr1');
  resultMap.put(ar.get('CaseId__c'),r);
}

return resultMap;

public class Result{
  Decimal sentTime;
  Decimal recievedTime
  String caseId;
}
```

Also... I think that you can do it without the first loop at all.

```
AggregateResult[] groupedResults = [  
   SELECT CaseId__c, SUM(sent_time__c), SUM(recieved_time__c)
   FROM Timer__c
   WHERE CaseId__r.CaseGroup__ = :groupId
   GROUP BY CaseId__c
];
```

If you wanted to add the caseId to the result object itself so it would be easier to display in a datatable, you could add `caseId` to the `Result` object (modified above)

Then just add that id to the `Result` and return the map `values()` instead of the map.

```
//...
r.caseId = ar.get('CaseId__c');
resultMap.put(ar.get('CaseId__c'),r);
//... 

//return an array rather than a map:
return resultMap.values();
```

Comment: I ended up just using the AggregateResult to display the results in the data table. It didn't like the output from the map. And it didn't like when I tried to convert it to a list even though the only difference were [ ] from the List vs { } from the AggregateResult List in

Comment: Glad it worked in the end. Sometimes you can end up with an array of arrays or somesuch. You need to look at the dev console to figure that out though.